# Appropriate way to abstract away a Database class/API?

Tags: c#, ms-access

Due to a policy, I have to use MS Access, but because it isn't supported in Entity Framework I decided to create my own class that abstracts away the MS access specific code as follows:

```
public class DB
{

    public string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
    public string fileName = "db.mdb";
    public string connectionString;
    public OleDbConnection connection = null;

    public DB()
    {
        this.connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " +
            "Data Source=" + this.path + "\\" + this.fileName;

        connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
    }


    public OleDbDataReader Read(String queryString)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
        return cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }

    ~DB()
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a number of questions:

1. Is this a good way to abstract away the database so I can more easily replace it later or is there a more reasonable way to do this?
2. How do I ensure the database connection is always closed when done?
3. Is there a problem if there are multiple instances of DB with open connections? i.e. can you have multiple connections to a MS Access database (or should I use a singleton pattern here)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question borders on “Too Broad” for Stack Overflow; consider testing each change against your actual deployable. That said, I can make a few general recommendations:

If you are going to “abstract” an API, make it match the interface you are trying to abstract to. For example, if you are targeting Entity Framework, make your class return `DbSet<YourClass>` instead of bare `YourClass` instances. This should allow you to switch to EF without code changes.

Make your `DB` class (terrible name; I suggest `YourBusinessModel`) inherit `DbContext`, implement `Dispose`, and use code like:

```
using (var bm = new YourBusinessModel(yourDbConnection))
{
    bm.YourEntities.Load(predicate);
    foreach (var ye in bm.YourEntities)
        DoSomethingWith(ye.InterestingProperty);
}
```

Do not use Finalizers unless you really really need them, and I don't think you need them.

It is really dangerous to try to make multiple connections to an Access database unless they are all read-only. If you have even one writer running in parallel, I suggest serializing access to the database. If this is too hard, making it a singleton is probably a good first version.